# JavaFX TableView implement "line selection" mode

Tags: java, javafx, tornadofx

I'm currently in the process of building a hex editor with JavaFX, more specifically its kotlin sibling [TornadoFX](https://tornadofx.io/) (which sadly means that I'm limited to JavaFX 8). To avoid re-inventing the wheel* I've decided to put my binary data in a good old `TableView`.

Unfortunately, the default selection behaviour (with cell selection enabled) is not adequate for my use-case. By default a 'range selection' (shift-clicking) produces something I'd call a "block selection":

[image: Block selection]

However, because the data in my table should be interpreted as a continuous string of bytes (like text), I want something like this:

[image: Line selection]

My question is: what would be the best way to implement this behaviour?

I could not find any existing (open-source) implementations, which I guess makes sense because I can't imagine this being a common requirement for a table. I've thought of three ways to do this so far:

1. Attach a change listener to the observable list returned by `getSelectedCells` and 'manually' add the extra cells that should be selected.
2. Implement my own version of `TableViewSelectionModel`. This would obviously be the most flexible option, but because I can't subclass the [default implementation](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/blob/bcd5fc1fd4f546158267aeecb788783258a7ad35/modules/controls/src/main/java/javafx/scene/control/TableView.java#L2012) it'd lead to massive code duplication. As far as I know I only need to override the `selectRange` method, more specifically [this for-loop](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/blob/bcd5fc1fd4f546158267aeecb788783258a7ad35/modules/controls/src/main/java/javafx/scene/control/TableView.java#L2627-L2636).
3. Implement a `TableViewSelectionModel` that delegates everything except `selectRange` to an instance of the default implementation (possibly acquired via reflection). This causes a lot less code duplication than option 2, but still requires copy-and-pasting most of the `selectRange` method, with only the aformentioned for-loop changed.

I hate copy-and-paste oriented programming so I'm not a big fan of option 2 and 3. The first option feels very 'sketchy' though, modifying the selection list while still handling the original change events.
I'm very much a JavaFX noob in this area though, so it's entirely possible that this is totally fine, or perhaps there's another (very easy) way to do this that I've missed so far.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

* Some of my reasons for using a table:

- Not re-inventing "UI-binding" (showing updated results)
- Not re-inventing 'click' (mouse position) handling
- Not re-inventing selection handling (apart from these changes)
- TornadoFX's `datagrid` component performed horribly

Comment: You probably won't like this opinion, but I don't think the `TableView` API is suited to what you're trying to do here, because it's highly opinionated concerning the role of rows (each row is an object) and columns (each column is a property of the object represented by the row). You have made this work for your example, but it seems pretty artificial (there doesn't seem to be a "natural" object representing a row, for example), and fighting against the API like this you're going to end up running into the kinds of issues you have with selection. How much data do you need to display here?

Comment: @James_D I definitely agree that I'm fighting against the API here, I already needed a workaround to even get my data in the table. If there's a better component to use here I'd be delighted to hear it, but the ones I tried so far created massive performance issues.
The amount data that needs to be displayed is of course dependant on the opened file size, for my own use-case this is in the regions of 10-20 MB but I'd like to support files up to a couple of GB's (with the appropriate performance hit of course). The `datagrid` component I tried before was already unusable at a single KB.

Comment: Yeah, I figured you probably wanted to support large data sets. The reasons you cite for using a `TableView` are probably quite easy to implement yourself; what the `TableView` gives you that isn't easy is the virtualization of cells, so that UI elements (cells) only exist for the data actually displayed, and are reused as the user scrolls, etc. ControlsFX has a [`GridView`](https://controlsfx.bitbucket.io/index.html?org/controlsfx/control/GridView.html) that might work (you'd still need to implement event handling and selection, etc.)

Comment: option 4: start with openjfx, open up and/or implement the selectionModel as needed, compile your own version and bundle with your app. Also not nice ;) But you'll run into walls everywhere (selectionModel is ill-defined, worse implemented and all collaborators - such as skin/behavior - have their own conflicting ideas about circumventing the limitations ;)

Comment: Another option (5?) would be to ignore the table selection model entirely (use CSS to make selected rows look the same as unselected cells, in the default "selection" sense). Then implement your own selection model (not even using the JavaFX classes) that supports what you need (e.g. single range is very easy, multiple ranges need a bit more work). Add mouse handlers to your cells to manipulate the custom selection model, and use a CSS `Pseudoclass` and a little CSS to display the selected cells the way you need. That may be the path of least resistance.

Comment: I think, on balance, if I were writing this I'd probably implement it from scratch. It's always preferable to use libraries when you can, but none of the existing controls are really close enough to what you want here. Even using JavaFX properties, if you want to get into the GB range of data, are going to be problematic from a memory consumption perspective. JMO.